# Creating different Class types, avoiding Single Table Inheritance or polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each User has_many Personas, each Persona belongs_to a User. There are 3 types of Persona - types 1 and 2 are created automatically when someone signs up and a new User is created. Persona type 3 can be created later at any time by the User via a form. I therefore need a way to tell the create action in the Personas controller which type of Persona to create. The only technique I know is to pass the persona_type to the create action. The trouble is, this leaves it open to a mass-assignment attack. The persona_type should not be chosen by a user. My question is, how can I tell the create action which persona_type to create without including persona_type in the permitted parameters?

I believe that STI or polymorphic associations are possible solutions to this problem. However, both seem like overkill when there is very little difference between the three Persona types. Even if these are the best solutions, I think this is an interesting problem and it would be good to know how to avoid persona_type in persona_params.

In the Personas controller:

```
def create
  @persona = current_user.personas.build(persona_params)
  if ( @persona.persona_type==1 || @persona.persona_type==2 )
    if @persona.save
    # not sure what to do here
    else
    # not sure what to do here
    end
  end
  if @persona.persona_type==3
    if @persona.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome, " + @persona.name
      redirect_to @persona
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
.
.
.
private

  def persona_params
    params.require(:persona).permit(:name, :persona_type)
  end
```

Comment: i don't understand your concern

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to achieve the same functionality without having :persona_type in persona_params. So persona_params should be: params.require(:persona).permit(:name)

Comment: Users should not be allowed to choose the type of persona they are creating. If :persona_type is permitted, it means they can choose.